# iterate over all databases, insert data into temp table and display data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to iterate over all databases, insert data into temp table and display data but I am getting the error:
Invalid object name '#TempTable'.
Why? I am using sql server.

```
DECLARE @name nvarchar(100);
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);

DECLARE crs CURSOR FOR
    SELECT name
    FROM [schSystem].[databases]

OPEN crs;
FETCH NEXT FROM crs
INTO @name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      -------------------------------------------
      SET @sql = 'SELECT TOP 100 *
      INTO #TempTable
      FROM '+ @name +'.[schCandidates].[tCandidates]
      ORDER BY id DESC';
      -------------------------------------------
      FETCH NEXT FROM crs
      INTO @name;
   END;

CLOSE crs;
DEALLOCATE crs;

SELECT *
FROM #TempTable; -- the error here: Invalid object name '#TempTable'.

GO
```

Comment: A temporary table only persists for the duration of the scope it was created in. You are creating the temporary table within your dynamic statement, which is an inner scope, and thus when you get back to the outer scope, it no longer exists. You'll need to create the temporary object outside of the inner scope *or* use a permanent table.

Comment: Side note: Having the same objects in multiple databases normally implies a design flaw. In this case, it seems you are using the database name to define information that should be stored in the table as a column. If you are storing the same objects in different databases you are implicitly defining that that data is separate and should not be used together; hence why you have performed separation processes. If you want to process them together, then the data should be in the same database and table.

Comment: But I don't want to create a temporary table with a specific list of all columns and their types. How to do that? I need to create a report. I can't change a database structure.

Comment: A table needs to be well defined, you can't create a table that doesn't have well defined columns and types... No such type of object (in SQL Server) exists that has a "fluid" definition.

Comment: Now I know everything, thank you Larnu and Charlieface.